# if condition in MYSQL for sorting distance and check status

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, if-statement

I am writing a code to show the nearest location of shops with their open status (like if the shop is open or close by month). I am using following code which is working fine for distance but I want to sort my list to show data with their open status and then sort the list with their distance. Can you please help to just put my PHP below if condition code into query
I have 2 columns `'start_date'` with value `'int'` as month and `'end_date'` ... I am using following php code to show the status in html as well. Can you please help me to improve my query to sort the result by their open status first and then sort it by their distance

```
$currMonth = date('m');

$query="SELECT *,
            6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - latitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +     COS($lat * pi()/180) * COS(latitude * pi()/180) *
            POWER(SIN(($long - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as
            distance, $currMonth >= start_date as open FROM table_name 
            GROUP BY Id HAVING distance <= $km ORDER by distance ASC ,open ASC";


if (($currMonth >= $row['start_date']) && ($currMonth <= $row['end_date']))
$Status = "open";
else
$Status = "close";
```

Comment: What data type is `start_date`?

Comment: have you tried putting the order clause the other way round? `ORDER by open ASC, distance ASC` instead of `ORDER by distance ASC, open ASC`

Comment: @Kaii was just writing the same thing

Comment: @Kaii But I want to put entire my if condition in the query
($currMonth >= $row['start_date']) && ($currMonth <= $row['end_date'])

Answer (score 1):

replace this line of your query

```
$currMonth >= start_date as open FROM table_name
```

with this:

```
IF($currMonth >= start_date AND $currMonth <= end_date, 'open', 'closed') as open FROM table_name
```

it uses an inline IF condition like this - `IF(condition, true_result, false_result)`

if the condition is true, the result is `true_result`. if the condition is false, the result is `false_result`.

You also need to change the order of your `ORDER` clause if you want to order by the open status first, followed by the distance:

```
... ORDER BY open ASC, distance ASC
```